# Is there a minimum required distance between window and kitchen countertops?

Tags: receptacle, kitchens, code-compliance, kitchen-counters, countertops

I'm planning on a kitchen remodel which will reduce the existing space between a window and the countertop. There is a required electrical outlet in this space.

I was wondering if there is any building code or at least a best practice for this.
My concerns are:

1. Is a space of about 3 3/4" between bottom of window and countertop ok?
2. Will I be able to fit the electrical outlet in there and if yes, it is ok code wise?

This outlet cannot be moved since one is required within 2 ft from the edge and I'm trying to avoid the pop-out one.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: Original setup]

And this is what the new configuration would be:

[image: Planned setup]

Comment: Is it absolutely imperative that you have a slightly larger window? Can the outlet go in the knee hole  under the cabinet?

Comment: We are not changing the window but the cabinet instead. If you look into the proposed plan we are getting rid of the little "desk area" and replacing it with actual base cabinets and that is what is reducing the space between window and countertop.

Comment: If you raise the desktop to the counter height, will the existing receptacles be affected? It looks like the cover plates sit a little lower than the counter height. This may be the biggest issue

Comment: @HariGanti it will be affected. I don't mind raising it a bit. It will be tight but it still fits in the 3 3/4"space. My main concern is whether the window this close to the countertop and the outlet in this tight space is a code violation.

Comment: I take it the backsplash will run right up to the edge of the windowsill?

Comment: The issue is more that you may interfere with the window's sill plate. From what I can see, you don't have more than ~2" of clearance under the window to the receptacle junction box, so I would guess there's a single 2x4". The horizontal orientation of the receptacles also makes sense with this, so it's unlikely you could actually raise them at all

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issue with the arrangement you plan to do. The only issue would be if moving the box required cutting the wall framing to allow the relocation. If the box is already protected by a GFCI outlet, that should cover any other concern that there may be.

Answer (score 0):

How your community adopts the electrical code in your area will dictate what is allowable. It is not uncommon to request and receive a variance for unusual situations.